# JAVAFX: Buttons with actions (open files)

Tags: file, button, javafx, action, toolbar

I am fairly new to Javafx and I would like to be able to add "Actions" to my toolbar buttons for example "Tutorial" to open a PDF from the project root.

Im a bit stumped and I wonder, is there an easy to way add buttons with actions to this code?

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button btnNewGame = new Button("New Game");
        Button btnConcede = new Button("Concede");
        Button btnNetwork = new Button("Network");
        Button btnTutorial = new Button("Tutorial");

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.getItems().addAll( new Separator(), btnNewGame, btnConcede, btnNetwork, btnTutorial);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        pane.setTop(toolBar);
        pane.setCenter(createContent());

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 675);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dam spill - OBJ2000 Eksamen 2016");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#CJHEEACB)? Or any other tutorials?

Comment: You just need the `EventHandler` and of course the action to perform inside of it !

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I will check out the tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    System.out.println("button pressed");
} );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.